# Where do I find the source code for the exit procedure

Tags: c, assembly, decompiling

I disassembled the following C call

```
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

and found out that it calls the exit procedure at an assembly level

```
call    exit
```

Where can I find the source code for this procedure so that I can study it and find out exactly what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [C library of your system](http://repo.or.cz/w/glibc.git/blob/b40a4e1a7bf7000018a8d1d1ee2f37f5c63e5a42:/stdlib/exit.c#l102). Which then eventually invokes your [operating system](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/exit.c?id=39a8804455fb23f09157341d3ba7db6d7ae6ee76#n843).

The links are for linux with glibc, you forgot to mention your environment.

Comment: Thank you! I am using a Linux environment